# Downloadable File - Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

For some reason when trying to download a file, it fails. I've tried few different ways, all of them failed. Than I read something about pdf/word files are "forbidden" in Gatsby ??!

The default `<a href="route-to-file" download></a>` doesn't seem to work, it shows failed to download. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is the file being copied to your `public/` folder?

Comment: It wasn't, but unfortunately, it doesn't resolve the problem.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

See [Importing Assets Directly Into Files](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/importing-assets-into-files/) and [Using the Static Folder](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/static-folder)

```
import React from "react"
import downloadFile from '../downloads/file.pdf' 

  const IndexPage = () => (
  <>
    <a href={downloadFile} download>Download the directly imported file</a>{` `}
    <a href="download.pdf" download>Download the file that is already in your static folder</a>
  </>
)

export default IndexPage
```